# MySQL JOIN table query

Tags: mysql, join, syntax

I hate asking for code but I just can't seem to do the below -

Staff

```
   | lastname  - name    - position |
   | Henderson | John    |  A       |
   | Howard    | Bob     |  B       |
   | Hendry    | Chris   |  B       |
```

Max_person

```
   | lastname  - change  |
   | Henderson | 0.9     |
   | Howard    | 0.2     |
   | Hendry    | 0.3     |
```

I have been trying to JOIN these 2 tables - adding the "POSITION" column of staff to the end of max_person.

What is the query to use here?

PS. Sorry about my previous question - I got the tables wrong and am now totally lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT mp.lastname,
          mp.change,
          s.position
     FROM MAX_PERSON mp
LEFT JOIN STAFF s ON s.lastname = mp.lastname
```

If there's no matching lastname value between the two tables, the position value will be NULL.  Change "LEFT JOIN" to "JOIN" if you only want to see the records that match...

### Design tables better

This is risky to join on the last name, because multiple people can have the same last name.  First name can also be duplicated yet represent a different person...